# find 3d point on a circle given the angle and radius

Tags: vector, geometry, trigonometry, point, angle

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7InNo.png

I am trying to find the green points using the angle ,radius and center of the circle. 
I am using this image that was posted by another member. 
I wish to find the green points, but in a 3d space instead.
I am able to get the x and y value but i am unable to get the z.

```
r = radius
X = r * cos(angle)
Y = r * sin(angle)
```

How can i get the value for z-axis?

Comment: Why do you not set Z = 0?

Comment: if i set z to 0 i don't get the correct value

Answer (score 1):

In the case of 3 dimensions you need 2 angles. Basically what you are doing is converting from spherical coordinates to cartesian coordinates. So your formulas can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: so if i only had one angle i won't be able to find the point?

Comment: then you should probably take another angle as constant, anyway you can't determine 3 dimensions by a radius and one angle.

Comment: i looked at the formula that you posted, how would i know which angle is the inclination and which is the azimuth?